# Spring beans in configuration file form a cycle (Kotlin, Redis)

Tags: spring, kotlin, redis, spring-bean

I'm new to Kotlin and working on a Spring application, trying to set Redis configuration. I keep getting this problem:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'redisConfig': Requested bean is
currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Description:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
┌─────┐
|  redisConfig defined in file [file]
└─────┘
```

I don't understand what exactly causes this problem and how to fix it. It seems to me that RedisConfig is being created inside RedisConfig, but I'm not sure and don't understand where this problem comes from.

Here's `RedisConfig.kt`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.MessageListener
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClientConfiguration
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate
import org.springframework.data.redis.listener.ChannelTopic
import org.springframework.data.redis.listener.RedisMessageListenerContainer
import org.springframework.data.redis.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer

@Configuration
class RedisConfig(val messageListener: MessageListener) {

    @Value("\${spring.redis.host}")
    lateinit var redisHost: String

    @Value("\${spring.redis.port}")
    lateinit var redisPort: String

    @Value("\${spring.redis.topic}")
    lateinit var redisTopic: String
    
    @Bean
    fun jedisConnectionFactory(): JedisConnectionFactory {
        val config = RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort.toInt())
        val jedisClientConfiguration = JedisClientConfiguration.builder().usePooling().build()
        val factory = JedisConnectionFactory(config, jedisClientConfiguration)
        factory.afterPropertiesSet()
        return factory
    }

    @Bean
    fun redisTemplate(): RedisTemplate<String, Any> {
        val template: RedisTemplate<String, Any> = RedisTemplate()
        template.connectionFactory = JedisConnectionFactory()
        template.valueSerializer = GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer()
        return template
    }

    @Bean
    fun topic(): ChannelTopic = ChannelTopic(redisTopic)

    @Bean
    fun newMessageListener(): MessageListenerAdapter = MessageListenerAdapter(messageListener)

    @Bean
    fun redisContainer(): RedisMessageListenerContainer {
        val container = RedisMessageListenerContainer()
        container.connectionFactory = jedisConnectionFactory()
        container.addMessageListener(newMessageListener(), topic())
        return container
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use your method *jedisConnectionFactory()* instead of a new JedisConnectionFactory class, in *redisTemplate* method.
Basicly, you should do the same as you do in *redisContainer()*